# PHP - empty array fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem : I'm actually trying to set up a connection but every time I tried to connect the array for the member I'm connecting with return an empty array.

I've checked the SQL command and there is no problem to find the member there. I checked that the form send the data and it does and there is no error marked on the page. The array is just empty for no reason to me.

here is the code :

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE pseudo = :login LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindparam(':login', $login);
$stmt->execute();
$membreRow=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    if(md5($m_passe)==$membreRow['mdp']){
        $_SESSION['login_session'] = $membreRow['pseudo'];
        header('Location: mesJeux.php');
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it returns :

> Array ( )

I can't find the mistake I could have made so if anyone knows I'd be very grateful, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you certain the query returns a result?

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Yes, I've tested it multiple times to be sure with differents login and it works just fine on the phpmyadmin

Comment: Does `$login` comtain a value???

Comment: Error checking `$ok = $stmt->execute(); if (!$ok) { //show the error}`

Comment: RiggsFolly > Thank you, I'll do it as soon as I get something that work. i'm actually working on an old project of my current employer so I haven't had time yet to chane the password hashing

Comment: also, its a good practice to add an `exit()` after a `header()` call

Comment: Or `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and get any errors thrown as exceptions you cannot lose or ignore

Comment: The $login does contain a value, i've check it and I'l try your idea

Comment: On your code you have `$stmt->bindparam(:login, $login);` all lowercase make sure you use camel case like so `$stmt->bindParam(:login, $login);`.

Comment: I already have the $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); and the error checking return nothing, also I added the exit and the camel case, thank you for the tips

Comment: Thy should use `fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instea of `fetchAll()`. It will return `false` on empty.